# Is there a concept of conditionally mutually exclusive?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I came across this idea when trying to solve a basic probability problem in a few different ways. I just wanted to know if there was a formalized term for whatever I am describing, but it seems to just be that after conditioning, events can become mutually exclusive.

For example, in the simplest case, if $A$ and $B$ are independent events, and we condition on the event that exactly one of $A$ and $B$ occurs, then it looks like 
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb P \bigg(A \cup  B \,\bigg |(A \cap !B) \cup (!A \cap B) \bigg )  \\ &= \mathbb P \bigg(A \,\bigg |(A \cap !B) \cup (!A \cap B) \bigg ) + \mathbb P \bigg(B \,\bigg |(A \cap !B) \cup (!A \cap B) \bigg ) 
\end{aligned}

This should also hold when the two events are not independent. This all would just follow from something like the inclusion-exclusion principle.

So my question is whether this is valid reasoning that can be used in more general cases. Thanks!

Edit: Since the example I gave is a bit trivial, here's another:
$\mathbb P (!A \, \cup \,  !B \, | A \cup B)$, so the probability that at least one of $A$ or $B$ does not occur given that at least one of them does occur. So here the events $!A$ and $!B$ conditional on $A \cup B$ are mutually exclusive, whereas before they both had the possibility of occurring at the same time.

Comment: $P(A\cup B\mid A\Delta B)=1$ since $A\Delta B\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: Ah! Let me edit the question a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is true that

$$P(!A \cup !B \mid A \cup B) = P(!A \mid A \cup B) + P(!B \mid A \cup P)$$

but off the top of my head I can't think of a problem where this equation would be useful, i.e. where the two RHS terms would be easier to evalulate than the LHS term, which BTW equals $1 - P(A \cap B \mid A \cup B)$.

Comment: Yeah the equality doesn't seem to be useful in most cases, but I like trying simple problems out multiple different ways just to make sure they match up. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  And trying math problems (_especially_ probability problems) different ways is to be commended!  Sorry if I sounded like I was pouring cold water on your idea.  :)  The point is there are two terms on the RHS but really just one term $P(A\cap B \mid A \cup B)$ on the left, and in most examples I can think of each of the three would be about of "equal complexity" to evaluate.